# Filter django queryset to only include the results in the given list

Tags: django

So i have made a 'recipe' web application in Django, where i have a feature called "User's cabinet" in which user can add any of the ingredients and he would be presented with an option known as 'Makeable recipes', in which the application would suggest the user of which recipes he would be able to make given his cabinet's ingredients. Now the problem is if i want the recipes to contain any of the ingredients in the cabinet i can do 'Recipe.objects.filter(ingredients__in=cabinet_ingredients). And if i want to filter all of the ingredients in the cabinet, i can do:

```
qs = Recipe.objects.annotate(count=Count('ingredients'))\
                .filter(count=len(cabinet_ingredients))
for ingredient in cabinet_ingredients:
    qs = qs.filter(ingredients=ingredient)
```

But if i want a subset of the cabinet ingredients (which makes more sense) such that the recipes should not contain anything outside of these ingredients and can contain anything in this list. For example given the 3 cabinet ingredients, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', i have to find the recipes with the following results:

```
Recipes with 3 ingredients:
('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
Recipes with 2 ingredients:
('foo', 'bar'), 
('foo', 'baz'),
('bar', 'baz')
Recipes with single ingredient:
('foo')
('bar')
('baz')
```

Any clue to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a table for ingredients, you can do something like:

```
# ingredients _not_ in the cabinet
inner_qs = Ingredient.objects.exclude(name__in = cabinet_ingredients)
# recipes that do not contain an ingredient that is _not_ in the cabinet
qs = Recipe.objects.exclude(ingredients__in = inner_qs)
```

Comment: Awesome! As an addendum, you might like to read the [`in` field lookup documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#in), especially the _Performance_ _considerations_ section at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

@cha0site's answer is mostly correct. However, that will result in two queries to the database, whereas only one is necessary. Use the following approach instead:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Recipe.objects.exclude(~Q(ingredients__name__in=cabinet_ingredients))
```

Comment: Hey, according to the docs, it will result in a nested query, which may be optimized by the database. I considered using Q objects, but wouldn't it be exactly the same as the original `Recipe.objects.filter(ingredients__in=cabinet_ingredients)`? Or am I missing something in the logic?

Comment: It's possible Django would send the inner query along with the outer query in the same request. If that's the case, then either approach may be just as efficient. However, `filter` is actually different. With your version and mine, we're explicitly excluding anything not in that list, whereas the `filter` in your comment would merely include anything that that had those ingredients regardless of whether they also had 1000 other ingredients not in that list.

Comment: I don't know but why this method gives different undesirable results than the one posted by cha0site.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, I think your query excludes all recipes that have none of the ingredients in the cabinet, leaving the recipes that have at least one cabinet ingredient and some other ingredients too.

Comment: @Chris, I think I figured out what's wrong with your query. What we both wanted to do was `Recipe.objects.exclude(ingredients__name__notin=cabinet_ingredients)`, but Django doesn't have a `notin` operator. So you used `~Q(...__in=...)`, but that doesn't have the same meaning as `notin`. The `~Q(...)` syntax means the complement of the `Q(...)`, so you'd get every line that was not selected by `Q(...)`. And so, `exclude(~Q(...))` cancels out to become `filter(Q(...))`.

Comment: That's exactly why it works. You're right. I'm selecting every recipe that that happens to have any ingredient in not in that list, but then I'm excluding all those. The result is only recipes that only have the ingredients in the list and nothing more.